# Find control that reside in other assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll

I have 1 solution that contain a reference to other dll class `fatherWeb`

I am trying to "find" a control that resides inside this dll.
In `Page_Load` event I am trying to get reference to control in `Header` of the `fatherWeb.dll`.
In fatherWeb Class, there is a page called `UserNew.Master` in that page `head` section there is a `asp:contentPlaceHolder` control with the ID of `ContentHead`:

```
<head>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentHead" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>  
</head>
```

In the second project that is loading `faterWeb.dll`
i am trying to get reference to the `asp:contentPlaceHolder` control with the id `ContentHead` using this code:

```
 var pageHeader = Page.FindRecursiveControl<fatherWeb.UserNew.ContentHead>();
```

But i am getting `null`.

Also tried this:

```
Page.FindRecursiveControl<faterWeb.UserNew>().FindControl("ContentHead")
```

and also

```
Page.FindRecursiveControl<faterWeb.PageHeader>()
```

But is resulted in that error:

> Page.FindRecursiveControl()  The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'AI.ScriptManager.Extension.ControlExtension.FindRecursiveControl(System.Web.UI.Page)' and 'AI.ScriptManager.Extension.ControlExtension.FindRecursiveControl(System.Web.UI.Page)'

`faterWeb.PageHeader` "PageHeader" suppose to be a page (ascx, aspx)in this dll?

If so this is not the right class name that i am looking. the right one is called  `UserNew.Master` which holds `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentHead" runat="server">` and this is the control i am trying to get..

How can i get it right?

Comment: It might help if you give the full error, so we know what the ambiguity is.

Comment: @Flater Sure, just edited the post..